# Violates the constraint of type 'T' when upgrading from .net6 to .net7 Rc1

Tags: c#, winforms, automapper, .net-7.0

I am trying to upgrade my WinForms project from .net6 to .net7 Rc1 after changing the Target Framework and updated the NuGet packages and when I run the project I get this error

> GenericArguments[0], 'System.Int32', on 'T
> MaxFloatT' violates the
> constraint of type 'T'.

on this line of code

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(host.Services.GetRequiredService<XtraMain>());
```

This is the code in Program.cs

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        WindowsFormsSettings.ForceDirectXPaint();
        DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
        DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        
        using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(host.Services.GetRequiredService<XtraMain>());


    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                builder
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables(); 
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<XtraMain>();
                services.AddPersistenceServices(context.Configuration);
                services.AddApplicationServices();
                services.AddSingleton<IFormFactory, FormFactory>();
            });
```

And this is the StackTrace:

> at System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition,
> RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[]
> methodInstantiation)    at
> AutoMapper.Internal.TypeDetails.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.b__10(MethodInfo
> extensionMethod)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.d__231`3.MoveNext()    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.UnionIterator`1.MoveNext()    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
> AutoMapper.Internal.TypeDetails.PossibleNames()    at
> AutoMapper.Internal.TypeDetails.GetMember(String name)    at
> AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.DefaultName.GetMatchingMemberInfo(TypeDetails
> sourceTypeDetails, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String
> nameToSearch)    at
> AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.ParentSourceToDestinationNameMapper.GetMatchingMemberInfo(TypeDetails
> sourceTypeDetails, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String
> nameToSearch)    at
> AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.DefaultMember.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(ProfileMap
> options, TypeDetails sourceTypeDetails, Type destType, Type
> destMemberType, String nameToSearch, List`1 resolvers, IMemberConfiguration parent, Boolean isReverseMap)    at AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.MemberConfiguration.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(ProfileMap options, TypeDetails sourceType, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String nameToSearch, List`1 resolvers, Boolean isReverseMap)    at
> AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.NameSplitMember.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(ProfileMap
> options, TypeDetails sourceType, Type destType, Type destMemberType,
> String nameToSearch, List`1 resolvers, IMemberConfiguration parent, Boolean isReverseMap)    at AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions.MemberConfiguration.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(ProfileMap options, TypeDetails sourceType, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String nameToSearch, List`1 resolvers, Boolean isReverseMap)    at
> AutoMapper.ProfileMap.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(TypeDetails
> sourceTypeDetails, Type destType, Type destMemberType, String
> destMemberName, List`1 members, Boolean reverseNamingConventions)    at AutoMapper.TypeMap..ctor(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, ProfileMap profile, Boolean isReverseMap)    at AutoMapper.ProfileMap.BuildTypeMap(IGlobalConfiguration configurationProvider, ITypeMapConfiguration config)    at AutoMapper.ProfileMap.Register(IGlobalConfiguration configurationProvider)    at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Seal()    at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__12_2(IServiceProvider sp)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
> key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__12_3(IServiceProvider sp)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite
> transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite
> transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
> scope)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at SmartWinForm.Program.Main() in
> C:\Users\MBoua\source\repos\SmartWinForm\SmartWinForm\Program.cs:line
> 30

Comment: Can you post the definition of `MaxFloatT` ?

Comment: The problem appears to be within the AutoMapper configuration.  It's impossible to tell what the Profile is from the stack trace because it's all done via reflection, but I would start by examining all your classes that configure Automap with CreateMap etc.

Comment: What is in line 30?

Comment: @PoulBak System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(host.Services.GetRequiredService<XtraMain>());

Comment: As @Neil says, the exception is thrown by `AddAutoMapperClasses()`, which has scanned your configuration and is trying to call a generic method. Perhaps on one of your types. Search your codebase for the reported parameter `MaxFloatT` and create a [mre].

Comment: I found a similar error in AutoMapper GitHub https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3988#issue-1252073376

Comment: It looks like AM needs tweaking, but that probably won't be complete until after .NET 7 has been release.  One of the many problems with trying to update your project to the bleeding edge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the alpha version, the problem was fixed
[AutoMapper 11.0.2-alpha.0.12](https://myget.org/feed/automapperdev/package/nuget/AutoMapper)

Comment: Updating to 12.0.1 (from 11.0.1) appears to have resolved a similar issue I encountered while updating a project from Dotnet 6 to Dotnet 8.